# There are infinite primes of the form $4x-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading this proof in the book Elementary Number Theory by William Stein (which you can download from http://wstein.org/ent/). It is a special case of Dirichlet Theorem.

Propositon 1.2.5 states there are infinitely many primes of the form $4x-1$. I don't understand the proof he gives. I will copy the proof first:

> Suppose $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ are distinct primes of the form $4x-1$. Consider the number $N=4p_1p_2\dots p_n-1$. Then $p_i$ does not divide $N$ for any $i$. Moreover, not every prime is of the form $4x+1$, if they all were, then $N$ would be of the form $4x+1$. Since $N$ is odd, each prime divisor $p_i$ is odd, so there is a $p|N$ that is of the form $4x-1$. Since $p\neq p_i$ $\forall i$, we have found a new prime of the form $4x-1$. We can repeat this process indefinitely, so the set of primes of the form $4x-1$ cannot be finite.

(1) $p_i$ does not divide $N$ for any $i$.

Why is this true? Is it because of $p_i$ divides $N=4p_1p_2\dots p_n-1$ and divides $4p_1p_2\dots p_n$ then it must divide $-1$?

(2) Not every prime is of the form $4x+1$, if they all were, $N$ would be of the form $4x+1$.

Why? If they all were, say, $p_i=4x_1+1$. I think the product would generate a $+4$, ending then with a number of the form $4x+3$. Trying to find a more precise form, it may be that $$N=\prod_{i=1}^n 4(4x_i+1)-1\\=4\left[4^n\left(\prod_{k=1}^n x_k\right)+4^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_{n-1}=1\\i_r\neq i_s \forall s,r}^n (x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\dots x_{i_{n-1}})\right)+\dots\\+4^2\left(\sum_{i_1,i_2=1\\i_2\neq i_2}^n (x_ix_j)\right)+4\left(\sum_{i_1=1}^n x_i\right)+1\right]-1\\=4\left[4^n\left(\prod_{k=1}^n x_k\right)+4^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_{n_1}=1\\i_r\neq i_s \forall s,r}^n (x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\dots x_{i_{n-1}})\right)+\dots\\+4^2\left(\sum_{i_1,i_2=1\\i_2\neq i_2}^n (x_ix_j)\right)+4\left(\sum_{i_1=1}^n x_i\right)\right]+3$$

(3) Since $N$ is odd, each $p_i$ is odd, so there is a $p|N$ that is of the form $4x-1$.

Didn't he say that  $p_i$ does not divide $N$? "So there is a $p|N$..." I don't understand how he gets that conclusion.

Comment: You are over thinking it.  If every prime dividing $N$ were $1\pmod 4$ then $N$ would be $1\pmod 4$ which it isn't.  Hence $N$ is divisible by some prime congruent to $-1\pmod 4$.

Comment: I think the correct sentence there is that "not every prime divisor of $N$ is of the form $4x+1$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Yes it is because $p_i$  would divide $-1$.

(2) $N\equiv -1\mod 4$. If each prime divisor of $N$ $q_j$  were congruent to $1 \mod 4$, we'd have $N\equiv 1\mod 4$.

(3)  No $p_i$ in the list can divide $N$. Hence there's *another* $p\equiv -1$ which divides $N$.